# Text from file field overflows column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I have a form which has column containing file field and image preview.
My problem is after choosing image, name of the image overflow columns.
[image]

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <label for="task_Asset">Asset</label>
  <i class="material-icons text-muted" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Valid formats are: .jpg .jpeg .png .bmp .gif. Maximum size is 5MB.">info_outline</i>
  <input id="picture-input" name="task[asset]" type="file">
  <div id="preview"></div>
</div>
```

I have tried to style that with css:

```
#picture-input {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

But it doesn't help at all.
Adding `max-width: 100%;` or `width: 100%;` doesn't help at all, it truncates name at 100%, but doesnt apply ellipsis.

Any idea how to fix that to use up to 100% width and apply ellipsis?

I've tried not 100%, but 95% `max-width` and this happens:
[image]
Would be great if "..." or would be last thing that user can read there. Or at least extension (so actual end of name) would be visible.

**It seems like Firefox has that problem:**

Here's how it looks in Chrome:
[image]
That's acceptable.

Comment: How about apply the `overflow` and `text-overflow` to the `div`? (not the `input`).

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Are the ellipsis applying at all?  They are showing on my end.

Comment: Without `width`? No. With it applies sometimes, for example 100-95% won't apply. 95-60% will apply "screenshot-412421...15" and under 50% nothing again, that's weird. Well anyway I need to use 100% or about that, so let's just say it doesnt not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this pen: https://codepen.io/Loutrinos/pen/XaYqmY
If you add a wrapper div with a `overflow:hidden` and do the same for the `input` it will hide the extra text by default.

```css
.container {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"><input type="file"></div>
```

Updated the code to reflect a percentage based layout

Comment: This does not work when you have responsive layout. It specifically has to be % value, not static size. Even more, when you have static width, you don't even need wrapper.

Comment: updated the markup and css, it still works as expected. Maybe there is another issue with your css that is making the input to not overflow.

Comment: But, you know... It doesn't work like expected. You just truncated half of button.

Comment: I updated again the code snippet to make it a bit bigger. Even with that issue the file still understands the `overflow:hidden` so please provide some more feedback about any css that is overriding the default behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the parent `<div>` to `overflow-y:auto` and the child `<input>` to `overflow-y:hidden`

```
div > #picture-input{
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#picture-input{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Edit 1: turns out setting `overflow-y:auto` to the parent serves only to allow scrolling in the child element. To hide the overflow completely you set it to `hidden` instead.

```
div > #picture-input{
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It has scrollbar now and it's not truncated at all.